# Git push from different branch but set upstream to pushed branch?

Tags: git, github

Suppose there are two branches; `branchA` and `branchB`. How can I push currently working at `branchA`  but setup upstream for `branchB` to itself and push it; so that later when I'm in `branchB`, just `git push` works?

I tried web search but to no avail!

Comment: I would _assume_ that if you push branch `X` (while working on branch Y), if you use `-u`, it should set it up for `X`, and not `Y`. So: `git push -u some-remote new`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.